# Darth Vader mask trademark copyright

Tags: copyright, trademark

Okay so I created a Typographic image.

(an image that forms the shape of something only using text/fonts)

Now i want to submit this as a piece of work for a university project 'create a typographic image' ....

What are my rights on this?  Seen as university's could take this as plagiarism?

This is an example of one : 
http://seaningsblog.com/post/105092941920/darth-vader-typographic-design-buy

Comment: Are you able to generalize this somewhat?  It seems to be coming off as a request for legal advice.  Maybe you'd be able to couch it in terms of whether typographic images would be considered unlawful derivative works.  I'd also edit out the reference to a personal blog, if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are protected by copyright law, so it's not just certain words like "jedi" that are protected. Indeed, "jedi" is so much in common usage that using it would not constitute proof that you copied a protected work. The image, however, is so similar to the original that one would have to conclude that the shape was copied, and that copying is what is regulated by law. The possibility exists that you could use a [fair-use defense](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/in-the-us-when-is-fair-use-a-defense-to-copyright-infringement) for your your mask. Only a paid attorney could give you competent paid advice as to how likely it is that such a defense would succeed.

Plagiarism is not a legal concept, it is an academic one, and you would have to consult with your university's authorities to know how they define plagiarism, especially in an artistic context.

Answer (score -2):

Tutor for me at the University (in the UK) said the image shape is not the problem it would be the words used such as 'jedi' 'darth' which may be copyrighted.

Comment: You probably shouldn't post your tutor's answer, especially since it shows a basic lack of IP legal knowledge.  For example, *if* those words are protected, they would be protected by trademark law, not copyright.