# Section 107 and 108 of the 1976 United States Copyright Act

Tags: united-states, copyright

I have seen an book [Chemistry Essential for Dummies](http://images.pcmac.org/Uploads/JeffersonCountySchools/JeffersonCountySchools/Departments/DocumentsSubCategories/Documents/Chemistry%20Essentials%20-%20The%20Most%20Basic%20Guide.pdf) on web which says that

> No part of this publication may be reproduced, stored in a retrieval system or transmitted in any 
>   form or by any means, electronic, mechanical, photocopying, recording, scanning or otherwise, 
>   except as permitted under Sections 107 or 108 of the 1976 United States Copyright Act

Is it legal to download this book under the sections 107 or 108 of the [Copyright Law](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html)?.I couldn't understand the sections since it's too lengthy and hard to interpret.Could anyone explain it in simple words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 108(a) is the most useful for an infringer who posts an entire copy of a protected work in public. Subsections(b,c) require that the copy not be made available outside the premises, which precludes internet posting; (d) requires a user request to make a copy; (e) applies only to items that are off the market and transferred to a specific user; (h) allows more copying in the last 20 years of the period when a work is protected (not applicable here). Subsection (a) allows a library or archive to make one copy of a work, as long as there is no commercial advantage to making the copy, the library is relatively public (it might restrict access to bona fide researchers), and a copyright notice is included: this has the fewest restrictions on copying.

The internet downloader is not a library or an archive, so the downloader is not granted any permission under 108 to make a copy. Under 108(a) a library can make no more than one copy available, but every uploading or downloading is "making a copy". A library would be contributorily liable for the illegal downloadings of their "customers".

It is difficult to know exactly what one can get away with under 17 USC 107 a.k.a. "[fair use](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/in-the-us-when-is-fair-use-a-defense-to-copyright-infringement/7684#7684)". I am fairly sure that posting a copy of a contemporary book in the open is not "fair use" even if the intent is to make it possible for dummies to study chemistry: such copying is not at all transformative, totally unlimited, and provides a significant market substitute for the protected work.

Comment: :Could you tell whether downloading books from [internet archive](https://archive.org/) is legal?

Comment: Yes and no. They do have a number of legal downloads where you can look for particular books. However, they also copy *everything* on the internet, so if there is a web page that has ever illegally posted a book, there is a good chance that it is there, if you know the URL. I verified that just now.

Comment: :Yeah that's very right.I think there should be a group to stop this _illegal_ copying in [internet archive](https://archive.org/)  isn't it?

Comment: :Does crawling this [website](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/302l/lectures/) violates U.S copyright laws?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "crawling". Let's say the application is "printing a copy of the document". Doing so is a violation iff there is no permission. I would interpret the author's actions as granting permission. He certainly could have been clearer why he put that stuff out there.

Comment: :Oh sorry.I meant to say about [downloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) websites.