# Intellectual Property Issues associated with a Public Speach?

Tags: intellectual-property

Can a public speech be copyrighted or otherwise protected with regard to intellectual property ?? *(with regard to Melania Trump’s speech before the Republican National Convention)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any text can be protected by copyright, as long as it has a fixed form. It is not completely obvious whether a fair use defense would succeed: the essentials are spelled out [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/in-the-us-when-is-fair-use-a-defense-to-copyright-infringement). The most important consideration is non-commerciality and lack of impact on market and the purpose of the use, so the chances are slim that an infringement accusation would gain legal traction.

Comment: So, for example, if I copyrighted the speech before giving it, and had marketed copies of the speech, then the material would be protected ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: Creative works are copyrighted and protected by copyright when created.

Comment: @feetwet  ....... thank you ! ...............

Comment: All you have to do is record it in some form. You don't have to market it.

Comment: This is the right argument. Neither Michelle nor Melania stand to "make money" on the speeches.

Comment: @TomAu That is not necessarily the case. *Epic* speeches like the Gettysburg address or Martin Luther King's "I have a dream" are regularly reprinted in book form for commercial publication. Admittedly it is unlikely that these speeches will have such lasting impact but you never know.

Comment: @DaleM: Let's just say that Melania made her speech for "non-commercial use," and parody.( I don't even want to vouch for Michelle.) I once ready about a court case where a candidate's opponent was allowed to "lift" the candidate's speech as a form of "parody;" arguably the case here, since Melania and Michelle are from opposite parties.