# Use of illegally downloaded fonts

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

If a person downloads a font illegally, but doesn't use it for commercial purposes, what are the legal and ethical implications of their usage?

- Could the font be ethically (and legally) used for personal documents that aren't distributed?
- Could it be used in the writing of a document that is later distributed, but in a different legally-attained font?
- Could it be used in internally distributed memos?
- Could it be used in non-advertising documents distributed under public domain (i.e. with no restrictions on copying and redistribution)?

I ask because many fonts are extremely expensive to purchase for someone of limited financial means, and because I have no intention of commercially distributing any media or documents in an illegally downloaded font.

Comment: What country are you asking for?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that there is no difference between the ethical answer and the legal answer, in this case. The law recognizes the property right which a person has when they create a thing, such as a font, and that right is encoded in the law of copyright. The relevant US federal code is contained in [Title 17](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17), which you can read (essentially identical laws exist in virtually or perhaps actually all countries). The important thing to understand is that there is not a distinction between "privately" trespassing on a person's property and "publicly" trespassing on a person's property. The violation of the owner's property rights comes from taking the material without consent.

There is a legally-recognized exception to the owner's rights, in the form of "[fair use](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/7683/4501)", which is widely misunderstood to mean "if it's not for profit, the property owner has no legal protection". Simply taking and using someone else's IP non-commercially is not "fair use".

Comment: Fonts are also commonly protected by design patents, which can create other causes of action outside copyright, but the result is the same.  Damages in a design patent case can be different than a copyright case, but when the use is non-commercial, the copyright statutory damages are likely to be higher. (Comment because the answer is better than this comment, but I wanted to point out the additional potential for patent protection).