# Legal to create a publicly-available multiple choice test on a publicly-available resource?

Tags: copyright, internet

I am a web developer, and also have children, and had the idea of creating multiple choice tests on a "resource".  Take for example a BBC nature documentary on Netflix.  Actually that's NOT public so it's a better example.  I want my son to really learn that so I come up with maybe 30-40 multiple choice or T/F questions about it, and post it so he (and others) could take a test.  I feel like this will really facilitate learning.  All of a sudden, he's got a real incentive to pay attention!

I am not giving access to the video.  You'll need your own access to watch it.  I am not copying any clips of the video.  But I am essentially commenting on the video and creating a resource that discusses the video.  Am I infringing on any copyright laws by doing this?

The other question as a corollary is, are there specific restrictions on the format of the questions?  Am I violating laws if I quote short sections in order to implement the question?  I will of course cite the resource name and location.  I'm thinking that a lot of educational blogs could have this type of testing associated with them as well, so this applies not just to videos or private resources.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking questions and having discussion about a work is not copyright infringement. [Copyright infringement requires copying](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/young_lawyers/publications/the_101_201_practice_series/elements_of_a_copyright.html).

When quoting short sections, you *are* copying, so the question turns into a [fair-use](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/in-the-us-when-is-fair-use-a-defense-to-copyright-infringement) or fair-dealing question.

- [Fair use primer from the US Copyright Office](https://www.copyright.gov/fair-use/more-info.html)
- [Report of the Register of Copyrights on the General Revision of the U.S. Copyright Law (1961)](https://www.copyright.gov/history/1961_registers_report.pdf): Kinds of uses that may be permitted under fair use include "*quotation of short passages in a scholarly or technical work, for illustration or clarification of the author's observations*".

Comment: Thank you - very well worded and good references esp. the first fair-use link.  It is my hope that this type of system will actually ENCOURAGE more readership or viewership of a resource - and I think that it will have that effect.