# Take part of a song slow it down a bit and put it on a loop

Tags: copyright, fair-use, music

Lets say someone hypothetically took the beginning part of a song and slowed it down a bit and put it on a loop for 3 min..

In this scenario the original song was copyrighted.

Would this be copyright infringement if someone then put the new edited song in a game and used it there?

Comment: Is there a reason you think fair use would apply here?

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim I guess the question is more what constitutes copyright infringement.. I tagged fair use because I thought it was somewhat related

Comment: The linked question is somewhat related, but ism not even close to a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In the US, when is fair use a defense to copyright infringement?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/in-the-us-when-is-fair-use-a-defense-to-copyright-infringement)

Comment: Taking a sample of a copyrighted song and then repeating it in your own work? Sounds somewhat similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Ice_Baby. And in that case it was not just repeated but more was added to make it more of an original word, although if you listen to both works, it's clear to anyone that one was sampled from the other.

Answer (score 1):

> Would this be copyright infringement if someone then put the new
> edited song in a game and used it there?

It would almost certainly be infringing in this case. There is very little room for the fair use defense in the case of sound recordings.